# How to use R1 to fly with the sword in Destiny

Tags: destiny

I'm trying to figure out how to use the sword with a Warlock.
I have maxed agility.  I get a good sprint and double jump, but I can't seem to keep a rythm to keep from falling.  I drop right away after the first R1, and make forward momentum, but keep dropping.  I see other vids where dropping is minimal, which is what I'm trying to replicate.

- At what point in the jump do I start slashing?
- Do I spam R1, or is there a periodic timing I need to hit?
- Where do I look (sky/straight ahead)

Any advice, articles or vids that may help with the mechanic of sword flying?

Answer (score 5):

One of my favorite pastimes

The trick is too keep on turning, either left or right. Try to maintain one side though

- **At what point in the jump do I start slashing?**: After you jump, the moment before you begin to fall
- **Do I spam R1, or is there a periodic timing I need to hit?**: Spamming is fine, but make sure you hit R1 after the animation of wing ends. Should be precise
- **Where do I look (sky/straight ahead)**: Camera position does not matter, but movement does. Remember to constantly turn after every slash.

Answer (score 3):

The basics are often overlooked for flying with the sword.

- Max agility in your build and in your weapon with +2 (common)
- Use max melee attack speed (commonly overlooked)
  Having max melee attack speed (bonus from arms and helmet) will allow you to swing the sword faster. As a result you will fly better and stay in the air longer.

If you are in the crota raid using the raid boots for extra agility will be beneficial as well.

All that is left is to jump as far in the air as possible while sprinting and begin "flying" at the peak of the jump. Spamming the button works just fine.

Comment: I don't think melee attack speed stacks on multiple armor pieces. Also having the Crota's End raid boots (+agility while carrying the sword of a swordbearer) also helps out.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill - It does stack. Just like grenade throw stacks.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the sword on crota to get past the bridge or just because you want to get somewhere faster, there are tricks to using that sword.

When you are jumping with the sword, at the highest point in your jump is when you start to swing.

To stay in the air with the sword, you need to spam the R1 button. Even if your not good at spamming you don't need to spam the button that fast.

When you are swinging the sword in the air, look straight ahead. If you want to move your direction use the left analog stick in the direction you want to go.

I hope this helped.